# Laravel 5.5 login failed in some unknown situations

Tags: php, laravel

I'm maintaining a Laravel 5.5 project. Recently, some user reported that they were unable to login and the browser showed the customized exception page instead.

However, no matter how I try, I just can't reproduce this bug, even unable to find any error logs in the log files. The only thing that may have some clue to this bug might be these users coincidentally said they use iPhone 8 plus to access(with Safari). Also, I can't find any solutions through the Internet, is there anyone who had met this problem before?

Comment: Don't think there should be anything related to login and the device, session and validation is on the backend, unless you have some JS for the login page. Do you have the message that the user reported was showing?

Comment: I may suspect they switched off cookies. That's usually the culprit I have encountered on mobile phones.

Comment: @thefallen They just sent an exception page and told me what device they used.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin Oh, I switched off the cookie, and the error really appeared, thank you so much!

Comment: You could try things like sentry or bugsnag, they are excellent for such situations.